# How to change content of a div which toggles another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My HTML is like this:

```
<div>
    <div class="action">Show details</div>
    <div>Some hidden details</div>
</div>
```

My current JS is this:

```
$(".action").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next("div").slideToggle('slow');
    });
```

**How can I also change the content of the `action` div to "Hide details" / "Show details" on each toggle?**

So it's clear to users that clicking on the link again will close the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".action").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $container = $(this).next("div");
    var title = $container.is(':visible') ? "Show details" : "Hide details" ;
    $container.slideToggle('slow');
    $(this).text(title);
});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/45Vz9/1/

Answer (score 3):

In your div click handler:

```
var next = $(this).next('div');
$(this).html(next.is(':visible') ? 'Hide Details' : 'Show Details');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(".action").toggle(
    function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next("div").slideDown('slow');
        $(this).html("Hide Details")},
   function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next("div").slideUp('slow');
        $(this).html("Show Details") 
    });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wmhty/11/)

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div>
     <div class="action">Show details</div>
     <div class="toggleDiv">Some hidden details</div>
 </div>
```

in Jquery

```
 $(".action").click(function () {
     //e.preventDefault();  //what is it doing here 
     $(".toggleDiv").toggle("slow");
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution:

```
$(".action").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var nextDiv= $(this).next("div");
    var title = nextDiv.is(':visible') ? "Hide" : "Show" ;
    $(this).html(title);
    $(nextDiv).slideToggle('slow');
});
```

[Demo on jsFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/Huske/49jpx/1/)